# Prevent Security Essentials from creating a system restore point before definition update?

Tags: system-restore, ms-security-essentials, av-definitions

It is really annoying (and baffling) that Security Essentials always creates a system restore point before updating its definitions. There is no good reason to do this and creating a 2GB restore point just for a 5MB definition update is absurd. (“Yeppers” [puts it well](http://askleo.com/why-does-microsoft-security-essentials-seem-to-interfere-with-system-restore/#comment-36125); does Microsoft not trust its own software? As someone mentioned, other security programs don’t need to resort to creating a restore point before definition updates.) It wastes space, clutters the restore points, and interferes with defragmentting.

Unfortunately it is proving difficult to find a way to prevent MS SE from doing this. One person who [asked about this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/mse-protect_updating/why-does-mse-create-a-restore-point-on-every/9bb0bb71-e4a7-4850-ae74-22e5b97521dd?page=2) got nowhere because the restore-point setting in SE only applies to response actions to scans, not to definition updates. Another person who [asked about it](http://forums.techarena.in/networking-security/1368962.htm) got a bunch of random, meaningless, brain-dead, almost robo-spam–ish responses.

Has anyone figured out a way to prevent Security Essentials from pointlessly creating restore points for definition updates (short of turning System Restore off altogether)? Is there an unexposed registry setting or something that can stop it?

Comment: I honestly feel more software should do this. With 6TB disks on the market, seems like we can afford the space, after this website prove there are tons of people who need to create more restoration points.  But I don't know how to disable this feature or if it even can be disabled.  I have notice most MS software create a restoration point when its updated.

Comment: "There is no good reason to do this" - They're making the Restore Point in case something in the new definitions cleans out something that rooks your computer -- that way you can recover.  Same reason they do it before applying Windows updates.

Comment: Those restore points have saved me valuable time when, as @techie007 pointed out, updates have been the reason for failures. BUT, I would say it should be "user choice" whether it is enabled. Sorry, I don't know how to disable it either.

Comment: @CharlieRB It _is_ user's choice; you either have System Restore turned on, or not -- your choice.  Alternatively, switch to a 3rd party software that doesn't do it -- again, your choice. :)

Comment: @Ramhound, whether you personally like it or not is not relevant, there should be an *option* to use it or not.

Comment: @CharlieRB, that doesn’t make it okay to **force** it on everybody without the choice to opt out. Microsoft does not know the circumstances for every single system in the world and cannot make a universal blanket rule, especially when it would be so easy to fix by setting it enabled as the default and allowing advanced users to turn if off.

Comment: @techie007, then all software should do that. Like that other person said, does Microsoft not trust its own software? Do they not test anything before releasing it? Turning System Restore off altogether is not the solution. This problem is not with SR, it is with Security Essentials. They can **easily** set it to enabled by default and provide an option for advanced users to turn it off for whatever reason. There is no reason to deny flexibility. Also, switching to another AV provider isn’t exactly a choice; MS tries very hard to keep people using S.E.

Comment: I'm beginning to think you're just looking to rant. The best part is that you tell Ramhound "whether you personally like it or not is not relevant, there should be an option to use it or not.".  User options are all about what the user _wants_, so it's exactly relevant.  Things the user _needs_ aren't optional.   Regardless, there IS a reason for it doing what it does, and just because you don't like it doesn't mean MS is a pile of losers who can't test software properly, or are just trying to 'deny flexibility'.  PS, I have 150+ machines here running something other than MSE, no problem. :)

Comment: I’m beginning to think you’re just being and apologist (employee?) Microsoft has lost all good-will with users in the past few years with its fascist and tyrannical methods and is turning into Google. I for one do NOT have a 6TB drive, so wasting gigabytes of space for restore points EVERY SINGLE DAY for Security Essential definition updates really infuriates me. I should not have to choose between wasting space for useless restore-points every day and not having any restore-points at all.